# Error setting up JavaFX on NetBeans despite VM options

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I was following [this](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-NetBeans) tutorial to set up `JavaFX` on the `Apache NetBeans IDE`. I created the library as instructed and created the `Controller.java` and `FXML` files (literally just copy/pasted from the examples, along with the `Main.java` and `HelloFX.java` files; I wrote nothing of the code itself).

I tried the solution on step 5 for the `JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application` error, but it just makes a new error pop up: `java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found`.

The directory the components are on is `D:\Programas\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\lib`, which I supplied as instructed (`--module-path "D:\Programas\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`). I also tried setting an environment variable as instructed [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) and using that instead (`--module-path $PATH_TO_FX$ --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`), to no avail.

I searched for solutions for a long time, but the questions either lack answers, or I just find the same tutorials over and over again, often for old versions of the `Java SDK` and/or `NetBeans IDE`.

I'm new to both `JavaFX` (I was learning `Swing` when I found out it's getting the boot) and the `NetBeans IDE` (I'm used to `Eclipse`), so I'm completely in the dark here.

EDIT: Added screenshot as requested. [image: Screenshot showing the location and VM arguments]

Comment: No, since the tutorial doesn't mention it. What should the file contain?

Comment: apologies, you don't need it. From my testing you appear to get the error `java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found` if the path you've given in `--module-path` doesn't exist... Are you certain that `D:\Programas\javafx-sdk-13.0.2\lib` exists and contains javafx-controls-13.0.2-win.jar ?

Comment: I'm certain it exists. I have it open right now, in fact. However, the file is simply called `javafx.controls.jar`.

Comment: The difference in filename is because you're using the SDK and I'm using JARs from maven central. I've checked with SDK. This works fine for me...  will keep looking.

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong when creating the `Controller.java` and `FXML` files. I copy/pasted their content from the tutorial I mention in the question. Was I supposed to use some NetBeans feature to generate them automatically or something?

Comment: The problem you're seeing "java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.controls not found" happens long before the JVM has even got to your code...

Comment: I thought as much, but I was hoping it was something I screwed up that was easily fixed, instead of this odd bug that apparently has no reason to occur in the first place.

Comment: I gave up and spent a few hours setting this up on Eclipse. It's working there. I'll try reinstalling NetBeans once I've got a decent grasp on JavaFX. Thank you for your help.

Comment: The only possibility I can think of is that there must be something not quite right about the module path. The "Module javafx.controls not found" definitely means that the --add-modules was "seen" by the JVM. Could you screenshot your Netbeans launch setup with the --module-path and also file explorer showing the JARs in that location to be 100% sure?

Comment: I added the screenshot, as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on GitHub that sort of worked. [Here](https://github.com/openjfx/openjfx-docs/issues/115#issuecomment-538640448) they say you can remove the VM arguments if you add the `JavaFX` library to the `Run` option in the libraries for the project, but I was only able to get everything to work by adding the library **and** keeping the VM arguments.